# Como gerar um arquivo no mesmo diretório do exe

Tags: c#

Estou gerando um arquivo XML e quero que o mesmo gere junto do exe.

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\dados\filmes.xml", null);
```

ao invez de por o diretório por pra salvar junto do exe.

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string caminho = Path.Combine(Enviroment.CurrentDirectory, "filmes.xml");
```

Extra:

Se tiver de trabalhar com caminhos favoreça o uso do [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) de forma a abstrair alguma da complexidade de criar caminhos correctamente.

Comment: Obrigado aos dois pela resposta, mas uma maneira que resolveu foi por o "." ex: ".\arquivo.xml" e ele gera junto do executável, estou utilizando o Visual Studio, mas acho que é uma particularidade da linguagem.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues tb e uma solução, neste caso ao usar o ponto esta a criar um caminho relativo. A minha solução e a do Renan iriam criar caminhos absolutos. Nada de errado nisso desde que o que esteja a usar para criar o ficheiro entenda caminhos relativos.

Answer (score 4):

Com isso:

```
string caminho = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Daí você obtém o diretório onde o executável se encontra. Você pode usar o método [`GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) da classe [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path(v=vs.110).aspx) para obter o diretório.

[Roubei descaradamente do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837501/2263584)

Comment: Esta é a única solução confiável para a pergunta. Outras formas podem funcionar por coincidência. O dia que a coincidência termina, ninguém sabe porque o programa deu pau.

Comment: @bigown no entanto, caso o ficheiro seja uma cópia sombra, o caminho retornado vai ser o caminho da cópia ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))